# why Array.prototype only output [] in console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

String.prototype

```
String {}
```

Object.prototype

```
Object {}
```

Boolean.prototype

```
Boolean {}
```

but `Array.prototype` outputs `[]`, why not `Array []` or something else? What happened?

Comment: I think this is due to the _Inspector_ internal formatter.

Comment: Because that's just how the console represents arrays. It's probably different in some other browser's console.

Comment: @Florent do you have any article about it ? thanks

Comment: Which console are you using? Please add the respective browser-specific tag

Answer (score 1):

**I looked into the ECMA specs and V8 source code, but I couldn't get a concrete answer.**

According to the [ECMA-262 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), every object must have algorithms for all of the essential internal methods, however, all objects do not necessarily use the same algorithms for those methods which means the output will be implementation specific at least in the case of **[[GetPrototypeOf]]**.

Hence, if you try the same in different browsers, you'll notice that the output is slightly different in each.

**Internet Explorer 11:**

```
Array.prototype
[object Array]  []

String.prototype
[object String]  {length:0}

Object.prototype
[object Object]  {}

Boolean.prototype
[object Boolean]  {}
```

**Firefox:**

```
Array.prototype
[object Array]

String.prototype
[object String]

Object.prototype
[object Object]

Boolean.prototype
[object Boolean]
```

**Chrome and Opera:**

```
Array.prototype
[]

String.prototype
String {}

Object.prototype
Object {}

Boolean.prototype
Boolean {}
```